# How to set the children height on absolute position parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have problem with how to make children size following its parent. The case below.

HTML

```
<div class="video">

  <div class="spot">
    <img src="..." alt="">
    <button>x</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.video {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.spot {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  /* width: 16%;  only height can affect image on content*/
}

.spot img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.spot button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -24px;
}
```

What I want to do is to make the image follow the spot height. Because if I set width (whatever size), the image will follow the spot width. Anyone know how to do this?

I also create jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/isatrio/yosfep6r/14/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is already following your `.spot` height. Check the border on `spot`. Or do you mean overflow? Or do you want your `.spot` to follow your `.video`?

```js
console.log(".spot height: " + $(".spot").innerHeight());
console.log("img height: " + $(".spot img").height());
```

```css
.video {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.spot {
  border: red 2px solid;
  position: absolute;
  height: 40%;
  /*width: 20%;*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.spot img {
  /*width: 150%;*/
  height: 100%;  
}

.spot button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video">

  <div class="spot">
    <img src="https://creativeblossoming.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/navy-living-room.jpg" alt="">
    <button>x</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Actually image not following height yet. What I want to do is `img` following `spot` height. The problem if I put `height` (not `max-height`), the `width` will fill 100%. I want like when set width the height is auto (following ratio). But it can't happen in that css code. if you play with code I commented, you'll notice.

Comment: @isatrio what do you mean exactly by the word "following"?

Comment: @isatrio do you mean changing spot `height` and img has to follow?

Comment: @isatrio I removed the comments above and img fits precisely within `height`, thus, it's been hard for me to understand precisely what the problem is.

Comment: @isatrio do you want the `.spot` to **crop** the image?

Comment: I want the `img` exactly have the same height with `.spot`

Comment: @isatrio I changed the code, tell me what do you think

Comment: Actually, it's working but what I wanted to do is using relative size '%'. It's because the media will dynamically responsive follow it's place. But thank you for helping me btw

Comment: @isatrio do you mean relative size on `.spot`?

Comment: @isatrio I changed to relative size. It's ok now?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I improve a bit to make it work on my side. Appreciate :)

Comment: @isatrio not even a +1! Damn you :)

Comment: My reputation make me can't +1, sorry. But I will edit my question post as solved

Answer (score 0):

You have set `max-width` instead of `width`. `max-width` will not set the `width` to the given value, it will just prevent the `width` from surpassing the given value.

```
.spot {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```